# Script Working with multiple items but not one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of images with links correlated to each image. I filter them by month right now. So last month, I had 7 images with links. This code would randomly select one of the images and its link to display. I am having an issue when I only have one image in the month. It works just the way I'd like it to when there is more than one image. But for some reason, the image won't show up when I only have one. I'd like to be able to display one image every time if there is only one image, or a random image every time if there is more than one.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/SQL.php';
    use myDatabase\SQL;

    $group = variable_get('govdocs_images_group');

    // get ids of images in this group
    $images = SQL::select('SELECT `id`, `link` FROM `govdocs_images` WHERE `group` = FROM_UNIXTIME(' . $group . ')');

// pick a random number between 0 and $image_count - 1 for seeking.
$rand = rand(0, count($images) - 1);

// print link and image html.
echo '<a href="' . $images[$rand]['link'] . '">';
echo '<img src="/myFilePath/img.php?id=' . $images[$rand]['id'] . '"/>';
echo '</a>';
```

Comment: Why not use the `array_rand()` function?

Comment: When there's only 1 image, `$rand` should always be `0`. What are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach instead.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/SQL.php';
use myDatabase\SQL;
$rand = 0;
$group = variable_get('govdocs_images_group');
// get ids of images in this group
$images = SQL::select('SELECT `id`, `link` FROM `govdocs_images` WHERE `group` = FROM_UNIXTIME(' . $group . ')');
// pick a random number between 0 and $image_count - 1 for seeking.
if(count($images) > 1) {
   $rand = rand(0, count($images)-1);
}
// print link and image.   
   echo '<a href="' . $images[$rand]['link'] . '">';
   echo '<img src="/myFilePath/img.php?id=' . $images[$rand]['id'] . '"/>';
   echo '</a>';
```

Comment: This prints every image when I have more than one. I want to randomly select one image to print. It also didn't work with just one image for some reason.

Comment: @threebubblesoup are you using some framework? Check the method `SQL::select` internally or locate it and post it's code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is failing, but you can improve it by doing the random selection in MySQL instead of PHP.

```
$images = SQL::select('SELECT `id`, `link` 
                        FROM `govdocs_images` 
                        WHERE `group` = FROM_UNIXTIME(' . $group . ')
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        LIMIT 1');
$row = $images[0];
// print link and image html.
echo '<a href="' . $row['link'] . '">';
echo '<img src="/myFilePath/img.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"/>';
echo '</a>';
```